# Как исправить ошибку Illegal offset type?

Tags: php, foreach, phalcon

`( ! ) Warning: Illegal offset type in UserController.php on line 56`

Эта ошибка возникает во время перебора массива `foreach ($validation->getMessages() as $message)`а конкретно ее причина `$message->getMessage()`

```
$response += [
                    $message->getField() =>
                        $message->getMessage()

                ];
```

var_dump($message->getMessage())

`string 'Имя персонажа занято другим игроком' (length=66)`

Весь код:

```
public function register()
{
    $user = new User();
    $response = [];
    $data = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);
    if ($data == true) {
        $validation = $user->validateRegistrationData($data);
        if (!count($validation->getMessages())) {
            $user->register($data);
           return $this->createOkResponse();
        } else {
            foreach ($validation->getMessages() as $message) {
                $response += [
                    $message->getField() =>
                        $message->getMessage()

                ];
            }
            return $this->createArrayResponse($response, 'errors');
        }
    }else {
        throw new \Exception('No post-data provided',ErrorCodes::POST_DATA_NOT_PROVIDED);
    }
}
```

Целый день крутил вертел, но так и не смог решить проблему. Ценным будет любой ваш совет.

Comment: `[(string) $message->getField() => $message->getMessage()];` - это не решение проблемы, а скорее костыль.

Comment: А может причина все-таки в `$message->getField()`? Что там?

Comment: Причина в `$message->getField()` метод периодически возвращает масив вида `Array
(
    [0] => 'login'
)` а иногда как и ожидается возвращает строку. 
Тут уже вопросы к фреймворку. Так как в документации написано
 `public getField ()`  Returns field name related to message", но никак не массив.

Comment: Сделал временный костыль 
`if (is_array($message->getField())) {
                        $response += [(string)$message->getField()[0] => $message->getMessage()];
                    }else{
                        print_r($message->getField());
                        $response += [(string)$message->getField() => $message->getMessage()];
                    }`

Answer (score -2):

А что вы хотите достичь кодом?

```
$a=[];
$a+=[''];
```

Я не знаю где вы могли видеть такую конструкцию, но если вы хотите добавить в массив элемент на php то это делается несколько иным способом

```
$a=[];
$a[]=[''];
```

В крайнем случае

```
$a[$b]=[''];
```

Comment: В принципе, операция вполне легальная: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php